# Can Axon guarantee a synchronous end-to-end request cycle using a DistributedCommandBus and a Clustering Event Bus?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, message-queue, cqrs, axon

Here is what I have in mind:

1. User create a command in the presentation layer in the MVC's Controller.
2. The command is sent on a `DistributedCommandBus`.
3. The command reaches the Command Handler.
4. The command handler raises few events.
5. The events are sent on a Clustering Event Bus that uses RabbitMQ for example.
6. The event is handled through the multiple different EventListeners.
7. The control is returned to the MVC's Controller again.

So basically I want everything to happen synchronously. I have some doubts that this might not be possible, but I want to know what is the limits of synchronous communication using a DistributedCommandBus and a Clustering Event Bus.

Comment: RabbitMQ and synchronous are two words that don't belong in the same sentence together. Sorry :-(

Comment: What about not using a CQRS/Axon approach? Sounds like you want to shoehorn the approach (CQRS) and the tool (Axon) in a way they were not intended for.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can force the command bus to be synchronous, but you can't force the clustered event bus to be synchronous,you might need to look at the simple event bus